# Non-probablistic notion of pth moment

Tags: real-analysis, probability, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

In probability, the $L^p$ spaces represent the different moments, such as $L^1$ finite expectation, $L^2$, finite variance, and so on. How can I think of this non-probabilistically? Is there a notion of "having finite pth moment" that corresponds to non-probabilistic notions of variance? How can I understand this?

Comment: A measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ has finite $p$th moment if $\int |x|^p d\mu(x)<\infty$. For a random variable $X$ with distribution $\mu$ this is then equivalent to $E(|X|^p)<\infty$.

Comment: What intuitively is finite pth moment? @Jochen

Comment: The **tails** $m(t)=\mu(\{x\in\mathbb R: |x|>t\})$ must decay fast enough: A standard application of Fubini's theorem yields $\int |x|^p d\mu(x)= \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}m(t)dt$ which thus must be finite.